# CDK Deployment of 2 Identical Apps To The Same Account For Different Environments

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

**Given a situation where the same AWS account will host the  `Dev` and `UAT` cloud deployments simultaneously, what is the best way to instantiate and segregate those 2 pseudo-environments?**

I say "pseudo" because the cdk `Environment` only takes in an account id & region.  There is no other separation mechanism.

I could hand down the prefix manually into resource names by passing variables to the `Construct` constructor call which is passed in by the `Stack` constructor

```
main(args) {

  app App = ...

  Stack(app, "stackid", bucketPrefix = args[0])
```

But I'm asking if there is a cdk/aws native way that enables this instead.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the [CDK best practice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-organization) is separate environments for Dev and UAT, it's certainly possible to deploy multiple app copies in the same account/region pair<sup>*</sup>.

1. Each app's stacks need a different construct id - e.g. `DevMyStack` and `UatMyStack`.  Child construct identifiers inherit their parent's scope, so passing the prefixes down the construct hierarchy isn't required.  The [docs have an example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/identifiers.html#identifiers_construct_ids) of duplicating stacks within an app, which has the same constraints as your case.
2. This assumes you are following the [best practice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps-names) of letting CDK/CloudFormation set resource names.  The Dev and UAT builds are ephemeral anyway, so this shouldn't be a problem.  If you prefer pretty names, consider setting explicit resource names only for production:

```js
bucketName: props.isProduction ? "my-explicit-bucket-name" : undefined
```

3. Add tags for better operational and cost control.  It's easy to tag to all stack resources in one go:

```js
cdk.Tags.of(DevMyStack).add('build', 'dev');
```

* Your apps should not contain "singleton" resources that are created once per account/region.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution won't exactly work.  `CfnParameters` have to be created within a `Stack` not an `App` so I cannot pass in the cfnparameter to all stacks.  Further, `stackId` & `constructId` cannot be based on unknown tokens which means I couldn't affect the auto-created names for resources.

Comment: OP does not mention use of `CfnParameter`, which is a [CDK anti-pattern](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/parameters.html). They run counter to the CDK's [synth-time decision-making](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps-synth) best practice.

Comment: @RamónJRomeroyVigil The good news is you don't need them.  Have two apps, `app-dev.ts` and `app-uat.ts`.  To keep things DRY, wrap all the stacks in a [new construct](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/constructs.html#constructs_author), which you  pass to both apps. The apps pass unique prefixes to their child stacks.

Comment: If I understand your suggestion then having separate apps would mean that if I want to promote changes from dev to uat I would have to copy the dev code into the uat app and then redeploy.  This seems arduous and manual.

Comment: @RamónJRomeroyVigil No.  Use construct composition and it's all DRY.  See the `MyService` [example in the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/stacks.html) for a 1-app approach to deploying 2 environements without the use of Cfn parameters. If there is a requirement is to simulate independent "promotion" of `dev` to `uat`, my 2-app suggestion may be better.  This is because it's easiest to deploy \*all\* stacks in an app.  But the concept is the same.  Add the `MyService` construct to 2 separate apps, which can then be deployed independently.

Answer (score -1):

Most constructs have a name attribute that can be assigned. CDK prefers you to leave this blank - doing so adds a random string of characters to the end of the generated name, allowing for multiple deployments in the same account-region.

This is not very human readable or easy to tell apart. Tags can help with this (tag each set with its own tag). My preference is to go ahead and use the Name fields, but programatically add a suffix

my-lambda and my-dynamodbTable become `blue-my-lambda` and `blue-my-dynamodbTable` vs `green-my-lambda` and `green-my-dynamodbTable`

just a simple variable concated string in the name attribute wil handle this, and still is mostly in line with `synth-time-decision-making` if you pass the name in from the stack constructor at the app level. This also prevents the need for multiple apps in your repo.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  Unfortunately, this is what I was suggesting in the question when I said "I could hand down the prefix manually into resource names by passing variables to the Construct constructor call".  I was asking for an alternative to this possibility.

Comment: ah. Fair enough. Unfortunately, I don't believe there is a better alternative than that -   It keeps your source of truth (the IaC of your infrastructure) as a singular point but allows you to customize and deploy multiple deployments in the same namespace (and also helps with things that are globally named, like s3 buckets